# An existing file not being identified using os.path.isfile function

Tags: python, filepath

I have a file 7.csv in directory: `'~/Documents/Jane/analyst/test/1/'`. I was able to read this file using `pandas.read_csv` function with no problem.

```
f_path = '~/Documents/Jane/analyst/test/1/7.csv'

pd.read_csv(f_path, index_col=None, header=0)
```

But when checking whether this file is exsiting using os.path.isfile(), the result return False.

```
os.path.isfile(f_path)

False
```

What could be the the possible error source?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Both `os.path.isfile()` and `os.path.exists()` do not recognize `~` as the home directory. `~` is a shell variable not recognized in python. It has to be either fully specified or you can use relative directory name.

But if you want to use `~` as home, you can do

```
from os.path import expanduser
home = expanduser("~")
```

Answer (score 1):

As hun mentioned, your code should be

```
import os

f_path = '~/Documents/Jane/analyst/test/1/7.csv'
os.path.isfile(os.path.expanduser(f_path))
```

This will expand the tilde into an absolute path. ~, . and .. do not have the same meaning to the python os package that they do in a unix shell and need to be interpreted by separate functions.

Comment: Works perfectly. Thanks!